# Writing Mysql Left join does not work?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this tables

**ARTICLES**

articles_id

article_name
article_qty
article_price
article_amount

**ORDERS**

orders_id
article_id
invoice_id
customer_id

**CUSTOMERS**

customers_id
customer_name
customer_position
customer_office

customer_invoice

When I do something like this

```
$sql="SELECT customer_name, article_name FROM orders LEFT JOIN articles ON article_id = articles_id LEFT JOIN customers on customer_id = customers_id";
```

It doees not get any results, what is the proper way to left join this two tables in one query?

I use CI 
Like this

```
$this->db->query($sql);
```

What i got i this

```
object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#28 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(31) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(52) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(2) ["row_data"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: Your query should be correct, although I would use table aliases to qualify all the column names.

Comment: Left join's won't filter out results from the first table and you have no `WHERE` clause.  Do you have any rows in the `orders` table?

Comment: Yes i have rows in orders

Comment: I am using codeigniter $this->db->query($sql);

Comment: When you say no results, do you mean 0 rows in the result set, or `NULL` values in the result set columns?

Comment: Ok, that is different than no results.  Then you do have a join problem.  Are there rows in `customers` and `articles` which match the rows from the `orders` table?  If so, then @reptilidarat's advice will probably correct your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an alias for any table join that you use like this:

```
$sql="SELECT c.customer_name, a.article_name FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN articles a ON o.article_id = a.articles_id 
LEFT JOIN customers c on o.customer_id = c.customers_id";
```

or you can use USING syntax like this:

```
$sql="SELECT c.customer_name, a.article_name FROM orders o 
LEFT JOIN articles a ON USING(articles_id) 
LEFT JOIN customers c on USING(customer_id);
```

Comment: I agree this is better form, but I'm not sure this is the cause of the problem.  Incorrect outer join criteria may cause the join to either return `NULL` for the columns on the right or result in more rows than desired (for example, if `articles_id = articles_id` is interpreted as the same table, then it will always equal itself).